# Counter column in a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, count, inner-join

I have a two tables that I link with an INNER JOIN. These are an Invoice Header table and the Invoice Lines table.

What I would like to add is some sort of counter column that would give me a 1 for each unique invoice number, while a 0 for any duplicate invoice number in case the invoice has more than one line item. It would then allow me to run a count on various columns in Excel when I analyze my data later on. Basically it's a count, but only on the records of the left table, ignoring the right table.

I just can't figure out how to use a COUNT() or a CASE to get this to work. Is it possible at all?

This is my query:

```
SELECT P.DocNum
     , L.LineNum
     , P.DocCur
     , P.DocTotalFC
     , P.DocTotal
     , CASE 
         WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 1) = '7'  THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 2) = '15' THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN L.AcctCode = '11501'       THEN 'MX'
         WHEN LEFT(L.Project, 1) = 'W'   THEN 'MX'
         WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '570'         THEN 'MEC'
         WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '590'         THEN 'ZHU'
         ELSE 'Flight Ops'
       END AS 'Type'
     , L.AcctCode AS 'Account'
     , L.OcrCode  AS 'Aircraft'
     , L.OcrCode2 AS 'Department'
     , L.OcrCode3 AS 'Business Unit'
     , L.Project  AS 'Project'               
     , L.LineTotal
FROM OPCH P
   INNER JOIN PCH1 L ON P.DocEntry = L.DocEntry
WHERE P.DocDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31'  
ORDER BY P.DocNum, L.LineNum
```

Any hints highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one is invoice number? Which version of `SQL Server`?

Comment: The invoice number is the DocNum field. The server is SQL Server 2008. The row_number over partition from Sagi does the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is `ROW_NUMBER()` and not `COUNT()` :

```
SELECT P.DocNum
     , L.LineNum
     , P.DocCur
     , P.DocTotalFC
     , P.DocTotal
     , CASE 
         WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 1) = '7'  THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 2) = '15' THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN L.AcctCode = '11501'       THEN 'MX'
         WHEN LEFT(L.Project, 1) = 'W'   THEN 'MX'
         WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '570'         THEN 'MEC'
         WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '590'         THEN 'ZHU'
         ELSE 'Flight Ops'
       END AS 'Type'
     , L.AcctCode AS 'Account'
     , L.OcrCode  AS 'Aircraft'
     , L.OcrCode2 AS 'Department'
     , L.OcrCode3 AS 'Business Unit'
     , L.Project  AS 'Project'               
     , L.LineTotal
     , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.docnum ORDER BY p.docDate) > 1
            then 0
            else 1
       end as rnk
FROM OPCH P
   INNER JOIN PCH1 L ON P.DocEntry = L.DocEntry
WHERE P.DocDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31'  
ORDER BY P.DocNum, L.LineNum
```

You didn't provide enough details to understand which column is the unique invoice number, and by what column you dicide who is the first one(gets value 1) and the duplicates(gets value 0) . I used `docnum` as the invoice number, and `docdate` as the column to decide which is duplicates, adjust it if needed.

If the order doesn't matter - its a total duplicate and doesn't matter which record is the duplicate, then the order by part doesn't matter.

Comment: The DocNum is the invoice number, as you correctly assumed.

Thank you very much. I knew the row_number() function but didn't know the "partition by" trick. Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As i haven't know exact data based on assumption i have used Row_number and Case condition we can get 1 for normal values and 0 for Duplicate values

```
SELECT P.DocNum
     , L.LineNum
     , P.DocCur
     , P.DocTotalFC
     , P.DocTotal
     , CASE 
         WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 1) = '7'  THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 2) = '15' THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN L.AcctCode = '11501'       THEN 'MX'
         WHEN LEFT(L.Project, 1) = 'W'   THEN 'MX'
         WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '570'         THEN 'MEC'
         WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '590'         THEN 'ZHU'
         ELSE 'Flight Ops'
       END AS 'Type'
     , L.AcctCode AS 'Account'
     , L.OcrCode  AS 'Aircraft'
     , L.OcrCode2 AS 'Department'
     , L.OcrCode3 AS 'Business Unit'
     , L.Project  AS 'Project'               
     , L.LineTotal
     , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY  P.DocNum,L.LineNum ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END SummaryValues
FROM OPCH P
   INNER JOIN PCH1 L ON P.DocEntry = L.DocEntry
WHERE P.DocDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31'  
ORDER BY P.DocNum, L.LineNum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT
        a.DocEntry, joincounter = count(b.DocEntry)
    FROM
        OPCH P AS a 
        INNER JOIN PCH1 AS b ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
    group by a.DocEntry
)
SELECT 
    case 
        when cte.joincounter > 1 then 0
        else cte.joincounter 
    end as joincounter

    ,P.DocNum
    , L.LineNum
    , P.DocCur
    , P.DocTotalFC
    , P.DocTotal
    , CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 1) = '7'  THEN 'Admin'
        WHEN LEFT(L.AcctCode, 2) = '15' THEN 'Admin'
        WHEN L.AcctCode = '11501'       THEN 'MX'
        WHEN LEFT(L.Project, 1) = 'W'   THEN 'MX'
        WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '570'         THEN 'MEC'
        WHEN L.OcrCode2 = '590'         THEN 'ZHU'
        ELSE 'Flight Ops'
    END AS 'Type'
    , L.AcctCode AS 'Account'
    , L.OcrCode  AS 'Aircraft'
    , L.OcrCode2 AS 'Department'
    , L.OcrCode3 AS 'Business Unit'
    , L.Project  AS 'Project'               
    , L.LineTotal
FROM 
    OPCH P
    INNER JOIN PCH1 L ON P.DocEntry = L.DocEntry
    inner join cte on cte.DocEntry = P.DocEntry
WHERE
    P.DocDate >= '2016-01-01' 
    AND P.DocDate < '2016-03-31'  
ORDER BY
    P.DocNum, L.LineNum
```